# Android Activity life cycle, print methods, save and restore

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Im really new to android and i have a little problem that i dont know how to solve.

Im having a small application that prints out the Activity lifes circles methods like this:

```
 protected void onCreate(){
 super.onStart()
 print("onStart was called"); //this is a void and its only printing a text
}

protected void onStart(){
 super.onStart()
 print("onStart was called");
}
```

and so on...

While im i portrait mode the app is showing all the methods on the screen but when i switch to landscape the activity object is of course destroyed and it  creates the first three methods again.

Im using onSaveInstanceState an onRestoeeInstaceState to try to save printed order on the screen while i switch from portrait to landscape.

How can i make it work?

example of app output in portrait mode:

> onCreate was called 
>   onStart was called 
>   onResume was called 
>   onPause was called 
>   onStop was called 
>   onRestart was called 
>   onStart was called 
>   onResume was called

i want theese prints to stay even if i switch to landscape.

This is onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState i dont really know how to solve the problem here.

```
 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the manifest I believe you are able to edit it to allow portrait and landscape displays and also have it recall the savedInstanceState. Sorry I can't give you a more detailed answer at the moment.